# Subspace of a normed space N

Tags: functional-analysis

If a subspace $L$ of a normed space $N$ is contained in an open ball then $L$ is the null space. How do I show this?

Answer (score 0):

If $L$ is not null, then there is a nontrivial $v\in L$ with $||v||=1$. $L$ is a subspace, so $kv \in L$ for any $k\in\mathbb{R}$. Take $k =$ two times of the radius of your ball for a contradiction.

Comment: I don't think that $k=2$ necessarily works.  You'd have to let $k>radius/norm(v)$.

Comment: Yes! Will edit!